# What are the prerequisites to run IBM System i Navigator Version 6 on Windows?

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I'm running IBM System i Navigator Version 6 on Windows 7 with below configuration-:
[image]
[image]
RAM-: 6 GB

I want to run **System i Navigator Version 6** on a **64-bit System**. So I want to know whether its possible to run this application on a **64-bit Processor** with **64-bit Windows OS**?

If answer is no then how can I run **System i Navigator Version 6** on a **64-bit System**?

Comment: Should be, did you try? What happened?

Comment: I didn't try yet. I'll try now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that System i Navigator 6 works just fine on Windows 7 64 bit. There is a 64 bit specific installer that should be included on your install disk, or it can be downloaded from IBM if your maintenance contract is current.

System I Navigator 7 also works fine on Windows 8 and Windows 10, both 32 and 64 bit versions - we use it daily on over 100 machines with a mix of all 3 above OS's.

See here for required PTF level information: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows/os.html